# What is A|B in conditional probability?

Tags: probability-theory

We define the conditional probability to mean
$$ \mathbb{P}(A \mid B) := \frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathbb{P} (B)} .$$

So as I see it, $A \mid B$ is only a notation. But what exactly is the set (event) in the sample space for which we are calculating the probability?

Comment: $A|B$ has no meaning by itself. It is not a set.

Comment: The partition belongs to the function; it is not a set operation.  $\Bbb P(~\mid~)$ is the probability measure of an event under a condition.

Comment: Formally, the symbol "$P(A|B)$" is simply an abbreviation of "$P(A\cap B)/P(B)$". The notation $A|B$ does not refer to an element of the $\sigma$-algebra of a probability space.

We define $P(A|B)$ in this way because we want it to represent the probability that $A$ occurrs, given that $B$ has occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \mid B$ is not a set, and $\mathbb{P}(A \mid B)$ is not computing $\mathbb{P}$ of any set.  The $\mid$ symbol only has meaning in the context of $\mathbb{P}(A \mid B)$; the symbols $A \mid B$ by themselves are meaningless.

For a vivid illustration of this, consider the sample space $\Omega = \{HH, HT, TH, TT\}$ with every outcome having probability 1/4.  Let $A = \{HH\}$ and $B = \{HH,HT, TH\}$.  Then $\mathbb{P}(A \mid B) = 1/3$ but there is no subset of $\Omega$ that has probability 1/3.